# How does the appengine datastore (java - JDO) store and return data, i.e. is it FIFO or LIFO? If its FIFO or NEITHER, how can I make it LIFO?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I was just wondering if I store some data chronologically, will it be returned back in the order of most-recent to least-recent OR least-recent to most-recent? For e.g. If I input data in the following order: `A[1], B[2], ...`, if I do a simple `select` query of the table, will it return the list as `{A, B, ...}` or `{..., B, A}`? Assume that I haven't set any indexes i.e. indexing is automatically set by appengine. A critical part of my system's design depends on this information, so I want to confirm this information before I proceed. Any help will be highly appreciated. I need the data retrieval to be in LIFO format, how can I ensure this?

- FIFO - first in first out
- LIFO - last in first out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the app engine datastore doesn't specify any guaranteed order, and that the persistence framework you use (JPA? JDO?) doesn't either. So if it's critical, then store a timestamp along with every data you insert, and add an `order by` clause to your queries to make sure you retrieve the objects in the appropriate order.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to do `order by` but as far as I know, you need to select the 'order by' entity as well. However, I'm trying to do a key-only query and order the queries by some other property. So for example, if I have a table of (key, data, date), I only want the keys of this table sorted by most-recent to least-recent

Comment: Have you actuelly verified that. SQL supports ordering without fetching, so JPA must support it as well, and I don't see why JPA over App Engine Datastore wouldn't support it : "select e.key from MyEntity e order by e.timeOfInsertion desc" is a valid JPA query, AFAIK.

Comment: Ah if that is true, then thank you for your answer. No, I haven't verified that, I just assumed that. Sorry for my misunderstandings and thanks again.

Comment: just because JPA supports something doesn't mean App Engine supports it.  There are plenty of JPA/JDO features that are not supported on AppEngine.  JPA was targeted at relational databases.  AppEngine is not a relational database.  (also, just because SQL supports something doesn't mean JPA does :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a sort order, data will be returned sorted by key.  If you haven't specified key names, the ordering of the keys will be by their numeric IDs, which are generally increasing but monotonicity is not guaranteed because of the way IDs are allocated among running instances. If you need to guarantee a specific ordering, store a timestamp and order on that property.

Answer (score 1):

The default sort order for entities returned by App Engine - if you don't specify another one - is first by any inequality you've filtered on, then by key. If you want to order by date, you should include a date field and sort on it explicitly.

It's perfectly valid to filter on a field of an entity in a keys_only query.